# Alternating edit text hint not visible for Arabic language

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is kind of weird that in my page where I have 6 edit text fields, only the alternative edit texts are showing hint and rest of them are not. This happens only from Android 4.0 and onward. I don't find any reasons for this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

mLang = mPreference.getString("lang", "");

bBlood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        bDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        bAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        bPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        mProfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


if(mLang.equalsIgnoreCase("English")){  
        }
        else{
            mProfile.setText(R.string.sign_up_arabic);
            bName.setHint(R.string.name_arabic);
            bDOB.setHint(R.string.name_arabic);
            bAdd.setHint(R.string.address_arabic);
            bPhone.setHint(R.string.name_arabic);
            bBlood.setHint(R.string.blood_arabic);
            mSignUp.setText(R.string.sign_arabic);
        }
```

And this is the layout for the above code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D5D2D2"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1border"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:background="#000000" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/l1border"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/name" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/age"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin5"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/address" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin6"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText7"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/phone"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin7"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText8"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/blood" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lin8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin8"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sign" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Screenshot looks something like this:

[image: Arabic]

Comment: Yes English works good, and Arabic also works good in lower end devices like Android version 2.0. But it is not working in Android version 4.0

Comment: No I havn't used typeface anywhere

Comment: Not related, but it seems redundant to put each `EditText` in a `LinearLayout` when it's the only component in the layout. You can safely remove these layouts for a cleaner, more efficient code (unless you inject views into them somewhere in your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen that this two EditText which have not shown hint are inputType set as "number" and "numberDecimal"., so please check one time removing input type.,It's may be creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
```

from linear layout