# Arabic language is not supported with the use of inputType

Tags: android, android-edittext

I had an issue with setting hint in Arabic language. Please refer [Alternating edit text hint not visible for Arabic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572800/alternating-edit-text-hint-not-visible-for-arabic-language?noredirect=1#comment27329187_18572800)
for details. The issue was with the use of inputType in the xml. I have removed it and now a normal keypad appears onclick of the edittext field. But I want the user to enter numbers only and I want numerical keypad to appear. How to do it?

In short, the use of inputType will not display the Arabic content and if it is not used then I am getting alphabetical keypad.

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

hope you can use this property android:numeric="integer" and please remove singleline property if you are using it.

```
              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_account_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="@string/hint_account_no"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:padding="@dimen/edittext_padding">
            </EditText>
```

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210160/edittext-hint-doesnt-appear-in-arabic-on-galaxy-note-1-with-android-ics/20780283#20780283 for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:inputType="number"` or `android:inputType="phone"` it should give you numeric keypad on click of edit text:

Following is the snippet from my xml, this should help:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:hint="my hint"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:id="@+id/Nummm"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColorHint="#767676"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```